# VB: Date format problem when loading *.csv

Tags: excel, vba, date

i have problem with excel changing the date format so it fits regional settings.

my problem is:
i am creating tool in which user chose which *.csv file to import and work with. While tool is on user side **i can't rely on regional setting** - tool have to work for all.
Problem is that excel automatically change date format to fits regional setting and therefore it is wrong or i can't parse it with static delimiter (like '/').

I know the format in which the date is written in the csv file (yyyy-mm-dd or dd/mm/yy) and **i would like to read that date as a text** so i can use DateSerial to create correct date.

Is there any way to read csv only as text and **prevent excel from changing it to date** (based on user regional settings) automatically ?

Thank you.

Comment: You can edit the formatting settings for the columns you use to date.

Comment: If there is already a date, changing it to text will break it into number. Like 2008-06-11 will be changed to 39610.

Comment: my bad, it works (.TextFileColumnDataTypes...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When importing, specify the column as text.

Or, put an apostrophe at the start of each date value.  This is the "this is a text value, don't reformat it" symbol.

example

```
123,'12/29/1999,blah blah
```

Comment: i had problem how to specify it as text, finaly done it. as i said before textfilecomundatatypes was the solution and i find it better than inserting apostrophe because i don't have access to all csv file that might be used.

Comment: Microsoft is sometimes too helpful.  My biggest grip is have with Microsoft is that they provide so much help that it becomes very difficult to do something they didn't anticipate.